# Redirect users to conversation once first message is sent?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using the below codes to let users create a new conversation on my website using PHP and MySQL (I know its outdated but not updating until website is finished.) I am trying to redirect the user to the conversation once they have sent the first message...

```
<form action="" id="newConvo" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>To: *</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" list="usernamelist" data-msg-required="Please enter a members username." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="to" id="to" required>
                        <datalist id="usernamelist">
            <? print "$searchlist"; ?>
            </datalist>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Subject: *</label>
                        <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['subject'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['subject']); ?>" data-msg-required="Please enter a conversation subject." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label>Your message: *</label>
                        <textarea id="body2" rows="7" name="body2" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid message." class="form-control" required><?php if (isset($_POST['body2'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['body2']); ?></textarea>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="hidden" name="from" value="<?php echo $user_data['username']; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

function create_conversation($user_ids, $subject, $body2, $to, $from){
    $subject    = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($subject));
    $body       = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($body2));
    $to         = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($to));
    $from       = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($from));


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `conversations` (`conversation_subject`, `sender`, `recipient`) VALUES ('{$subject}', '{$from}', '{$to}')");



    $conversation_id = mysql_insert_id();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_messages` (`conversation_id`, `userid`, `message_date`, `message_text`)
            VALUES ({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['userid']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '{$body}')";

    mysql_query($sql);

    $values = array("({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['userid']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 0)");

    foreach ($user_ids as $userid){
        $userid = (int) $userid;
        $values[] = "({$conversation_id}, {$userid}, 0, 0)";
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_members` (`conversation_id`, `userid`, `conversation_last_view`, `conversation_deleted`)
            VALUES " . implode(", ", $values);

    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Would I add something at the bottom of the function, maybe a header to redirect them to say for example:

```
header( 'Location: messages.php?page=3&conversation_id=$conversation_id' ) ;
```

or something like that?

Comment: Yes, you can redirect with `header( 'loation: ...`  What is the question?  Is it not working?

Comment: No it's coming up on my page as "invalid conversation id" as the link is actually redirecting to "conversation_id=$conversation_id" instead of say "conversation_id=12" like how it's meant to work...  ?

Answer (score 0):

You idea is basically correct, but remember that any header can be set only while there is nothing written to the output yet. 
Be sure that function with this header command will be called before any other html code will go.

And also, use double quotes for header contents if you want it to work correctly

```
header("Location: messages.php?page=3&conversation_id=$conversation_id");
```

or

```
header('Location: messages.php?page=3&conversation_id='.$conversation_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Baed on your comment it looks like the problem is your single quotes.  PHP treats strings inside single quotes as the written string (no variable substitution) but performs variable substitution inside double quotes.  Try:

```
header( "Location: messages.php?page=3&conversation_id=$conversation_id" ) ;
```

(Assuming the value of `$conversation_id`is correct already)